# Молога — происхождение названия

Tags: этимология, топонимика

От каких слов произошло название реки и города Молога и что оно обозначает? (исключая версию из этимологического словаря Фасмера).
Спасибо.

Comment: Название вопроса очень содержательно... Может поправите? В духе "Этимология топонима Молога"...

Comment: >исключая версию из этимологического словаря Фасмера  
  
Почему его надо исключать?  
Нет, я вполне допускаю, что все могут ошибаться, но в чем корнкретно?

Answer (score 2):

А версия топонимического словаря не подходит? Мне кажется вполне оправданным такое объяснение: Молога - река. Название оставлено древним населением края: основа мол - не объясняется из совр. языков, но широко представлена в зоне от Поочья до Сухоны и Вага: Мола, Маланга, Молонда, Малого (басс. Костромы), Молохта, Молокча, Молокша. Форманты, сопровождающие эту основу, известны по древней фин.- угор.гидронимии и сводятся к терминам со значением 'река'.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geo/3269/B0Географические названия мира: Топонимический словарь. — М: АСТ. Поспелов Е.М. 2001.

Comment: Короче, Вы за финно-угорский или балтийский след. Правдоподобно.

Comment: Не секрет, что добрая половина российских гидронимов - финно-угорские.